# Is it possible to call logoutOtherDevices without a password?

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I noticed that `logoutOtherDevices` calls the  `rehashUserPassword()` method:

```
protected function rehashUserPassword($password, $attribute)
{
    if (! Hash::check($password, $this->user()->{$attribute})) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('The given password does not match the current password.');
    }

    return tap($this->user()->forceFill([
        $attribute => Hash::make($password),
    ]))->save();
}
```

(Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9c44052743b0ee7f3adea36994918b4d8019e8b3/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php#L691C20-L691C20)

Is it possible to however to use it without a password for certain users that use LDAP to connect but are stored with an empty password in the DB?

I can use a workaround by hashing some hard-coded password like 'password' and then it works (I checked):

```
Auth::logoutOtherDevices('password');
```

But maybe I can do it better and actually call it without a password?